# Win Percentage Question

Tags: percentage, weighted-mean

I have noticed my gambling win percentage (in online pool) is very hard to increase as time goes by.  After 1500 games, I'm stuck at 57%.  If I want to increase my overall win percentage to 60% after playing the next N games, what should my win percentage be for these next N games.

Answer (score 8):

This is a simple weighted average, call your next $N$ games' win percentage $p$, an solve for the following:
$$\frac{1500 \times 0.57 + p \times N}{1500+N}=0.6$$

Comment: Thanks. This really shows that once you have an established win percentage, it's very hard to change it. I'd have to win the next 100 games to get to 60%! That's highly unlikely. I might be able to win 70% of the next 100 games. If so, my win percent would increase to 57.8% -- hardly worth the effort. Although a future rate less than 57% for most games will surely decrease my overall rate. I've noticed in the pool game, and also in the poker game I play, new user statistics show a relatively high win percentage.

Comment: @Dan With no further information about the game I might guess that the high win percentage for new users happens because a new user who wins once or twice at the beginning may stay around for a while. If they are unskilled or unlucky their win percentage will decrease when they are no longer new.  A new user who loses the first few games doesn't stick around.

Comment: @Ethan  It is my guess that most games are rigged to allow new players to win more often.  I have verified this in the poker game I play. When I play, I can readily see the stats for each player at the table, and it is always the ones with fewest games played that have the good hands - they are given to them by the game.  I remember when I first started, I got many strong hands (probabilistically unfeasible) in the first 500 or so plays.  That way, most newbies will stay around for awhile, and develop a passion for the particular game, and buy chips  - common for long timers that are hooked.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for confirming my guess - with a vengeance. I hadn't imagined the premeditation on the part of the game.

Answer (score 6):

@gunes has covered the answer.

Probably worth pointing out that there are constraints on the values $(p, N)$ that satisfy that equation (assuming $N>0$ and $0\leq p\leq 1$).

Regardless of your future win rate, you will need to play a minimum of 113 games going forward.

[image]

Comment: (+1) for the solvability remarks